# jQuery Mobile 1.4.0 - Change data-dismissible without pageload

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a jQM panel that I'm trying to change the data-dismissible attribute on without reloading the page.

Currently I have

```
$( "#panel" ).panel( "option", "dismissible", true );
$( "#panel" ).attr('data-dismissible', true);
```

which successfully manipulates both the panel's options and changes the data-dismissible attribute - however, it seems that jQueryM doesn't register that the change has happened and the panel will not close without a explicit close event.

See [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mL3uqbc5/2/).

Comment: I dont think it's possible without `.panel("destroy")` first and then re-build it. http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/cp2ax0fb/